# If a cell value appears in a separate column, return true

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

This question may already exist but here's what's going on. I've got a table with two columns and a different number of values in each column. I want to see if the value in column A appears somewhere in Column B - and if it does to return true.
Here is a small sample of my data. Not sure if there are any matches here or not.

[image: Data Sample]

Comment: First problem is that the left column is numbers, and the right column is numbers stored as text.

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNUMBER(MATCH()):

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(TEXT(A1,"0000000"),B:B,0))
```